Can only apply part of KDE theme
I am trying to apply this theme to my desktop: https://store.kde.org/p/1294729

Or any theme really. And I am getting this unexpected behavior when I click "apply theme"

It seems to only apply parts of the theme, regardless of which theme it is only the icons and windows change. I have tried downloading it manually and putting the theme in the folder, same result.

I have also tried installing it with the pling store, same result.
I've been working on this for a few hours and can't find any solution.
